# Overlapping circles with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to draw the below shape for my app. I can draw circles but couldn't intersect them with a different color.

[image: overlapping circles]

How can I do that?

I draw 2 circles but the intersection of them was not a different color.

Comment: you can use stack, and use opacity to add color to each shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stack widget and use `Positioned` widget to place circle.

```dart
   final double circleRadius = 100;

    final circle = Container(
            height: circleRadius * 2,
            width: circleRadius * 2,
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: const CircleBorder(),
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.3),
            ),
          );
```

And using with Stack

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: circleRadius * 2,
  height: circleRadius * 1.5,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: -circleRadius * .5,
        left: -circleRadius,
        child: circle,
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -circleRadius,
        child: circle,
      ),
      // circle
    ],
  ),
),
```

Will give you

[image]

Tweak the size & color.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets)